# Python pygame continuos image loading FPS

Tags: image, performance, pygame

Using pygame on a linux machine, continuously loading new images and displaying them slows down the program.

The input images (400x300) are in PPM format to keep the file size constant (360K) - not to affect IO and avoid any decompression delays.

It starts off at 50 frames per second and then after around 2 minutes its around 25 frames per second.

```
import pygame    
pygame.init()    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600),pygame.FULLSCREEN)   
frame=1

while 1:

    image = pygame.image.load(str(frame)+".ppm")    

    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(240)

    frame=frame+1
    if(frame%10==0):
        print(clock.get_fps())
```

What can be done to keep the frame rate more consistent?

Most likely it has something to do with old references to images that need to be garbage collected. Maybe not.

Is there anyway to load images continuously without creating new objects and triggering the garbage collector or whatever is slowing the system down?

Comment: Try printing to console less often, maybe frame%50. That can have an impact on performance.

Comment: @pmoleri I'll do that but doubt outputting fps 5 times a second is stressing the computer out.

Comment: Yes you are right. How many different frames are you loading? Are you looping? Perhaps there's some kind of optimization you can make. Also how about trying bmp format instead of ppm?

Comment: @pmoleri tens of thousands unique images. BMP format is near enough PPM (afew bytes difference) so don't think that would help much.

Comment: Ok, I would give bmp a try though, perhaps it loads faster. If you want steady fps you could lower it tick(25). Also you could profile the program to find out which method is decreasing performance after 2 minutes.

Comment: Having a lot of lines in the shell can actually stress the computer out quite a bit.  Try `print(clock.get_fps(), end='')`

Comment: @pmoleri I'll try BMP and its a good idea to profile line by line.

Comment: Do you have to use ppm? Because there are realtime video formats you can use.

Comment: @monkey No. You have any suggestions for "realtime video formats"?

Comment: There was another thread where they had to compress the video realtime, they were using `h.264`.  I asked because it sounded like your goal was to display video rather than images, you probably will get better performance saving and loading as any video format, if You don't require the encoding while the app is running.

Comment: @monkey Only images and to display them as fast as possible. Thats the goal.

Answer (score 1):

After many weeks of pondering, I think I finally figured out what your problem is.  For some reason, the computer must be remembering the old values of `image`.  After the line that blits, put

```
del image
```

I'm not entirely sure, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I think I tried this method of removing the image reference but did not get the constant frame rate. I'm going deeper and getting better results but still looking for the enlightened way. I'll post back here if I find out anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame    
pygame.init()    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600),pygame.FULLSCREEN)   
frame=1

global image
image = pygame.image.load(str(frame)+".ppm")
#this image can be used again and again
#you can also give ////del image//// but it will load from the first so it takes time but using again and again doesn't do so
while 1:
     screen.blit(image,(0,0))
     pygame.display.flip()

     clock.tick(240)

     frame=frame+1
     if(frame%10==0):
        print(clock.get_fps()):
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions.